# How do I repair a peach tree branch split in middle?

Tags: fruit-trees, repair

One of the branches of my white peach tree has split in the middle due to the excessive weight of too many fruits. The size of the branch is about that of an adult arm. Initially, I tried to squeeze the split together and wrap a bandage around it, but it didn't move at all. Since it's a visually appealing branch, I would like to repair it instead of cutting it off.

What options do I have? A quick Google search suggests using a bolt and nut to tighten the split. Would that work?

[image]

Comment: Step zero would be to put the support crutches (forked stick, props, call them what you will) you should have placed earlier to prevent this from happening out to support and lift the overloaded branches. If you simply ry to close the gap without doing that, it will just break again. I have my doubts if this can, indeed, be "fixed" at all at this point. But the longer you wait the lower the odds. And it will be weak here for years, so you might as well get your support sticks made, you'll need them for years.